# hex instead of base64 in BinData() - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

Is there a way to send hex of binary value instead of base64 to BinData() in mongo ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you want to convert it to hex after retrieving it? You have it in hex and need base64 to save it? Can you edit the question with an example?

Comment: @wdberkeley, for example use `BinData(0,"0565AF71")` instead of `BinData(0,"BWWvcQ==")`

Comment: So you want to transform hex data into base64. I don't think there are helpers for that in the shell - you ought to transition to using a driver, like the Node.js driver, where you can use a library to do the conversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
HexData(3,"00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
```

or

```
UUID("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff")
```

will both result to:

```
BinData(3,"ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==")
```

And the other way around:

```
BinData(3,"ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==").hex()
```

will result:

```
00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff
```

Answer (score 1):

If your mongodb driver uses javascript, then you should try `BinData(3,"ABEiM0RVZneImaq7zN3u/w==").toString('hex');`

I didn't find another way, because there is no `hex();` function in JS

Answer (score 0):

Only Use `HexData(subtype, hexstr)`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please **edit** your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.